# Black artifacts on skobbler map with sdk 2.1.0

Tags: android, sdk, skmaps

I use 2.1.0 version of Skobbler SDK and often get artifacts on map. How I can fix it?

Screenshot - https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLflG.png

Comment: On which device/os are you getting this behavior? Or is it the simulator?

Comment: This screenshot taken on simulator but I get this bug also on 4.0.4 and 4.1.2 devices.

Comment: Could you tell when these artifacts become visible? During panning/ zooming, or are they always visible?

Comment: For example, I open new activity with description when user clicks on marker on map. When he closes activity with description and returns to activity with map - artifacts are shown. Sometimes artifacts dismisses with zooming in/out, sometimes they stay visible until activity close.

Comment: Can you reproduce the behaviour in the demo project?